# Копирование одного столбца таблицы в другой

Tags: postgresql

мне необходимо ускорить запрос к базе данных. Суть такова, у меня есть запрос к базе, джоины запроса представлены на рисунке

```
            FROM
            issues
            LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (users.id = issues.user_id) 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON (events.issues_id = issues.id)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN address ON (address.id = events.event_location_data_id)
```

Таблица **events** используется в качестве соединяющей с таблице **address** и в *select* она не участвует. Поэтому для ускорения запроса я решил взять столбец **events.location_data_id** и скопировать в новый столбец **issues.address_id**

Для копирования элементов я написал такую команду

```
insert into issues (address_id)
select event_location_data_id from events 
right join issues on events.issues_id = issues.id;
```

И запрос получился такой

```
            FROM
            issues
            LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (users.id = issues.user_id)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN address ON (address.id = issues.address_id)
```

Но данные это некорректно. Данные предстают не в таком виде, в котором подразумевалось изначально. Ошибка заключается в копировании элементов столбца **events** в **issues**

Подскажите пожалуйста, где моя ошибка и как правильно нужно было написать *INSERT INTO*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите скриншоты и вставьте код в специальный блок (в редакторе где вы набираете вопрос есть кнопка "добавить код")

Comment: Также стоит уточнить заголовок. Используйте кнопку править